# Windows applications logs

Tags: windows, logging, history, setup

Is there a way to acquire a complete history/log of what has been installed/uninstalled on a Windows XP system since it's Windows OS setup date, except the Application Log (MSIInstaller) entries on the Add/Remove programs entries?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your question is "Other than the log that tracks programs being installed/uninstalled, is there a log that tracks programs being installed/uninstalled?"

No. There are plenty of ways to see what current programs are installed, however other than the event log entries you ruled out nothing else is tracking programs that where uninstalled at some point in the past.

Comment: You are right on the "uninstalled" part. As far as the "installed" part i found out that freeware Pdq Inventory [link](http://www.adminarsenal.com/pdq-inventory/main) does the job quickly..that is if you don't have the time for WMI, vbs etc scripting way...

Comment: Pdq Inventory would fall under the "There are plenty of ways to see what current programs are installed" category.

Comment: If you are no longer seeking answers you should click the check mark outline on the answer that applies best to your question, otherwise your question will still keep showing up on the front page seeking new responses. If you do not like any of the answers given but are not longer looking for new answers you can give your own answer and accept that.

Answer (score 1):

PDQinventory - for now - provides a list of installed s/ware along with the date of installation...